# Change value of column to a value from a foreign column

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

Hello my table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_eav(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  k TEXT NOT NULL,
  v TEXT,
  v_link INTEGER,
  UNIQUE(k, v) ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
  FOREIGN KEY(v_link) REFERENCES posts(id) ON UPDATE ???
);
```

v_link is the id column of another table, "posts". When it's not null, the "v" column should take the value of the "title" column from "posts".

When the referenced post record is updated, I'd like to change the "v" column on this table to the "title" column of the posts table. Is that possible?

Something like

```
... ON UPDATE SET v = posts.title
```

but of course this doesn't work :(

I made this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON my_eav
WHEN v_link IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  UPDATE my_eav SET v = (SELECT title
              FROM posts
              WHERE id = v_link);
END;
```

But I don't know if it's correct

Comment: This is what joins are for, is there any reason that you do not want to use a join?

Comment: I know but I don't think join works inside create table statement

Comment: No, but thats not the point. If you inner join the tables when querying for data, you can get `my_eav.k` and `posts.title` together.

Comment: This it what [triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) are for.

Comment: @AnnaK. Keeping two tables in sync via triggers can be tricky. That's why people usually normalize their databases, so they don't have to do it. What is the broader problem? It may be solved without having the `title` duplicated in another table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to use join as stated above.

```
select * from my_eav 
left join posts on my_eav.v_link = posts.id
```

But, if you want triggers, you'll get them. ;) 
You can test all code below on http://sqlfiddle.com/ with option 'SQLite (WebSQL)' 
And you have to choose query terminator - pipe [/]

```
CREATE TABLE posts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT)/

CREATE TABLE my_eav(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  k TEXT NOT NULL,
  v TEXT,
  v_link INTEGER,
  UNIQUE(k, v) ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
  FOREIGN KEY(v_link) REFERENCES posts(id)
)/

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger_ins
AFTER INSERT ON my_eav
BEGIN
  UPDATE my_eav SET v = (SELECT title FROM posts WHERE id = NEW.v_link) where id = NEW.id;
END/

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger_upd
AFTER UPDATE ON my_eav
WHEN (OLD.v_link <> NEW.v_link) or (OLD.v_link is not null and NEW.v_link is null)
  or (NEW.v_link is not null and OLD.v_link is null)
BEGIN
  UPDATE my_eav SET v = (SELECT title FROM posts WHERE id = NEW.v_link) where id = OLD.id;
END/

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger_b_ins BEFORE INSERT ON my_eav
WHEN NEW.v is not null and NEW.v <> (SELECT title FROM posts WHERE id = NEW.v_link)
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'V must be from posts.');
END/

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger_b_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON my_eav
WHEN NEW.v is not null and NEW.v <> (SELECT title FROM posts WHERE id = NEW.v_link)
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'V must be from posts.');
END/

CREATE TRIGGER update_posts_title UPDATE OF title ON posts 
BEGIN
  UPDATE my_eav SET v = new.title WHERE v_link = old.id;
END/
```

Here are few tests. Let`s fill tables with some data.

```
insert into posts (title) values('Romeo')/
insert into posts (title) values('Hamlet')/
insert into my_eav(k, v_link) values('test1', 1)/
insert into my_eav(k, v_link) values('test2', 2)/
insert into my_eav(k) values('test3')/
```

Check my_trigger_ins - OK

```
select * from my_eav

id  k       v       v_link
1   test1   Romeo   1
2   test2   Hamlet  2
3   test3   (null)  (null)
```

Check update_posts_title - OK

```
update posts set title = 'Romeo1' where id = 1

select * from my_ea

id  k       v       v_link
1   test1   Romeo1  1
2   test2   Hamlet  2
3   test3   (null)  (null)
```

Check my_trigger_upd - OK

```
update my_eav set k = 'test11' where id = 1

select * from my_ea

id  k       v       v_link
1   test11  Romeo   1
2   test2   Hamlet  2
3   test3   (null)  (null)
```

Check my_trigger_b_ins - OK

```
insert into my_eav(k, v, v_link) values('test1rrrr', 'rrrrr', 2)

Result: could not execute statement due to a constaint failure (V must be from posts.) - OK
```

Check my_trigger_b_upd - OK

```
update my_eav set v = 'xxxx' where id = 1

Result: could not execute statement due to a constaint failure (V must be from posts.) - OK
```

Thats All. Use `left join posts`really.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you're saying, it sounds like this is the main goal:

> Keep the **v** column in the **my_eav** table synchronized with
>   the **title** column in the **posts** table.

If this is right, my first thought would be that you could normalize the database by just storing the title in `posts` only, and if you need the title, just retrieve it whenever you query `my_eav` with a join:

```
select * from my_eav inner join posts on my_eav.v_link = posts.id 
where my_ev.id = <my desired record>
```

However, it's achievable using triggers for sure.

You didn't include the `posts` table design, but it sounds like it's something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT);
```

So let's insert a couple of sample records in there:

```
insert into posts (title) values('Romeo & Juliet');
insert into posts (title) values('Hamlet');
```

Which gives us a table like this:

```
--------------------
|id |title          |
--------------------
| 1 |Romeo & Juliet |
| 2 |Hamlet         |
--------------------
```

Now let's create the `my_eav` table with the foreign key (I left out the unique constraint for now so we can focus on the triggers).

```
CREATE TABLE my_eav(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, k TEXT NOT NULL, v TEXT, 
v_link INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(v_link) REFERENCES posts(id));
```

So now the blank `my_eav` table looks like this:

```
-------------------
|id|k  |v  |v_link |
-------------------
-------------------
```

Let's test the foreign key to verify that it doesn't allow records in `my_eav` unless they exist in `posts` (with my sqlite instance I had to use the pragma command to force sqlite to honor the foreign key):

```
pragma foreign_keys=on;
insert into my_eav(k, v_link) values('test', 3);
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

So that's good, we can't insert a record into `my_eav` if it doesn't exist in `posts`.

To keep the title synchronized between the two tables, we're going to need **two** triggers, not just one: a trigger on `my_eav` when a record is first created, and a trigger on `posts` when a title is changed there.

Here's the trigger on `my_eav` to grab the title when a record is first inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER get_title AFTER INSERT ON my_eav 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE my_eav SET v = (select title from posts where posts.id = v_link);
END;
```

If we test it by adding a record:

```
insert into my_eav(k, v_link) values('test1', 1);
```

It grabs the title like it's supposed to:

```
-------------------------------
|id|k    |v             |v_link|
-------------------------------
|1 |test1|Romeo & Juliet|1     |
-------------------------------
```

Another rec:

```
insert into my_eav(k, v_link) values('test2', 1);
```

Table now:

```
-------------------------------
|id|k    |v             |v_link|
-------------------------------
|1 |test1|Romeo & Juliet|1     |
|2 |test2|Romeo & Juliet|1     |
-------------------------------
```

and one more:

```
insert into my_eav(k, v_link) values('test3', 2);
```

Table now:

```
-------------------------------
|id|k    |v             |v_link|
-------------------------------
|1 |test1|Romeo & Juliet|1     |
|2 |test2|Romeo & Juliet|1     |
|3 |test3|Hamlet        |2     |
-------------------------------
```

Now, here's the second trigger we need to create, which will keep `my_eav` updated when changes occur in `posts`. **Note that we're creating this trigger on the `posts` table.** In your sample code, it looked like you were trying to *pull* the changed value from `posts` using a trigger on `my_eav`, when in reality you need to *push* the changed value to `my_eav` using a trigger on `posts`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_title AFTER UPDATE ON posts 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE my_eav SET v = (select title from posts where posts.id = v_link); 
END;
```

Now let's test it by updating a title in the `posts` table:

```
update posts set title='Othello' where title='Romeo & Juliet';
```

Check that the update occurred:

```
select * from posts;
```

Table now shows:

```
--------------------
|id |title          |
--------------------
| 1 |Othello        |
| 2 |Hamlet         |
--------------------
```

And if we check `my_eav`,

```
select * from my_eav;
```

The trigger on `posts` kept it in sync:

```
-------------------------------
|id|k    |v             |v_link|
-------------------------------
|1 |test1|Othello       |1     |
|2 |test2|Othello       |1     |
|3 |test3|Hamlet        |2     |
-------------------------------
```

Hopefully I understood the problem right and this helps.

Comment: Keeping two tables in sync via triggers can be tricky. There are at least two more ways to break the sync. 1) `UPDATE my_eav SET v_link = 2 WHERE id = 1` We changed the link to point to another post, but `v` is still the same. Will your current trigger on `my_eav` handle `UPDATE` correctly or it works only on `INSERT`? 2) `UPDATE my_eav SET v = 'Hobbit' WHERE id = 1` We changed the copy of the title to something that doesn't even exist in `posts`.

Comment: Yep, I see your point, if you truly want these to be rock-solid in sync, you'll need to address every possible thing that can happen. It's like trying to synchronize offline databases; you end up with situations where the user has to be the tiebreaker. This is a good illustration of why you should try to normalize. When you start using databases you wonder "what's so bad about storing in 2 places" until you see firsthand when data gets out of sync, and then it dawns on you, "oh that's why."